# How to display sidebar content using angular ui-router?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

On home page i have sidebar and Main content , when i click on sidebar items i want to display sidebar content to right side where i have Main content. I want fixed sidebar on all the pages only main content should change and rendered data based on states. How can i achieve that task using angularjs routing ?

home.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s3">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li ui-sref="desktop"> Desktop</li>
                <li ui-sref="laptop"> Laptops</li>
                <li ui-sref="monitor"> Monitors</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s9">
        <h1>Main Content</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

routes.js

```
angular.module('computerTrading').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
      controller: 'MainController'
    })
    .state('contact',{
      url:'/contact',
      templateUrl:'views/contact.html',
      controller:'ContactController'
    }).
    state('inventory',{
    url:'/inventory',
    templateUrl:'views/inventory.html',
    controller:'InventoryController'
    }).
    state('laptop',{
      templateUrl:'views/laptop.html',
      controller:'LaptopController'
    })
    .
    state('desktop',{
      templateUrl:'views/desktop.html',
      controller:'DesktopController'
    })
    .
    state('monitor',{
      templateUrl:'views/monitor.html',
      controller:'MonitorController'
    });
});
```

Comment: You could leverage `named view`'s of `ui-router`

Comment: I think you are already achieving that in your current code. But you forgot `ui-view` directive in your Main Content

Comment: @CozyAzure I have already `ui-view` in `index.html` , do i need to use it again in `home.html` ?

Comment: @PankajParkar can you please provide some example how i can achieve named views ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a `ui-directive` at your `col s9` part:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s3">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li ui-sref="desktop"> Desktop</li>
                <li ui-sref="laptop"> Laptops</li>
                <li ui-sref="monitor"> Monitors</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s9">
        <h1>Main Content</h1>
        <div ui-view></div><!--you need this-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KknjK5uoee4Rqd35v9IO?p=preview)